# Unable to show a popup element when user hovers over another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a popup element when user places a mouse over an other element:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
        $('#base').hover(
          function handleIn(e) {
            var popup = $('<img/>', {
              id: 'popup',
              src: 'http://placehold.it/32x32'
            });
            popup.css({
              'position': 'absolute',
              'z-index': 300,
              'left': e.pageX - 30,
              'top': e.pageY - 30
            });
            popup.mouseover(function() {
              console.log('mouseover');
            });
            popup.mouseout(function() {
              console.log('mouseout');
            });
            $('#base').append(popup);
          },
          function handleOut() {

          }
        );
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img id="base" src="http://placehold.it/256x256">
  </body>
</html>
```

Why doesn't the popup element show up? It is added to DOM, but I don't see it.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: Please read the [`.hover()` docs](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) to understand how do you should do it.. **Hint:**  replace `function handleIn(e) {` to `function(e) {`

Comment: @Mosh Feu "replace function handleIn(e) { to function(e) {" -- for what?

Comment: Wrapping `#base` to the `div` tag helps, but I don't really understand why. Is it somehow related to the fact that `img` tag doesn't have a closing tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't append a child to an `<img/>` element. See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/img.html)

Try append it to the parent

```js
$(function() {
        $('#base').hover(
          function handleIn(e) {
            console.log("asd");
            var popup = $('<img/>', {
              id: 'popup',
              src: 'http://placehold.it/32x32'
            });
            popup.css({
              'position': 'absolute',
              'z-index': 300,
              'left': e.pageX - 30,
              'top': e.pageY - 30
            });
            popup.mouseover(function() {
              console.log('mouseover');
            });
            popup.mouseout(function() {
              console.log('mouseout');
            });
            $('#base').parent().append(popup);
          },
          function handleOut() {

          }
        );
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="base" src="http://placehold.it/256x256">
```

By the way, that way you will have a new element on every hover event.

Comment: How can I decide whether I can append child elements to the certain tag?

Comment: 'A void element is an element whose content model never allows it to have contents under any circumstances.' from here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element . So the list are: `area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you help me with the following question btw -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35315030/how-to-intercept-mouseout-event-for-the-top-level-tag-only

Answer (score 0):

Try with this tooltip example:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>

  <img src="images/yourimage.jpg" class='test' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='right' title='your custom message' />

  <script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```