# How to intercept mouseout event for the top-level tag only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It seems that the `mouseout` callback from jQuery attached to the `div` tag containing several children elements will be called each time when user dragged a mouse away from any of these children elements. Am I right?

If so, how can I intercept the top-level tag mouse event only?

Comment: Use [mouseleave](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)   **↬** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258615/what-is-the-difference-between-jquerys-mouseout-and-mouseleave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `mouseout` bubbles, which means you can put an if statement to check and see if the target is the parent and put your code inside that.

https://jsfiddle.net/ck0kbowt/ for example :)